# Send notifications to the owners of a Gallery chat room when a user requests access

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications

When a user requests access to a Gallery chat room, they must wait until a room owner checks the "access" tab on the "info" section of a chat room and grants them write privileges. I think that the owners of the room should be notified when a  user requests access to the chat room, in order to make the process faster (and less annoying for those awaiting to chat there). What do you think about this?

Comment: I'd also like to add that, in my opinion, notifications should be updated after access is granted by a room owner.